# RHEL 6.5 / Updating MySQL

Tags: mysql, rhel6

Currently running RHEL 6.5 and need to update to MySQL 5.5.36. Currently it has MySQL 5.1.73 installed. The Software Collections repo has been added. I performed a yum update and it does not show me the option to upgrade MySQL.

What do I need to do to perform an upgrade, or will I have to uninstall and install a new mysql instance? There is no data on mysql yet.

Comment: Redhat includes MySQL 5.5 as part of the Software Collections.  Maybe start there http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/08/08/software-collections-quickstart/

Comment: I have the Software Collections added. However, when I do a yum update/upgrade it does not show the option to upgrade.

Comment: I haven't personally used the SCL, but that blog post looks like a good writeup

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install the package `mysql55` it wont update your 5.1 package.